# How to uninstall miniconda via homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, uninstallation, apple-m1, miniconda, macos-monterey

Using MacOS Monterey, m1 chip.
Installed homebrew and used homebrew to install miniconda.
However, the Miniconda which was downloaded via homebrew did not work. Rather, the miniconda installer works.
Thus, i would like to uninstall the miniconda that was downloaded via homebrew (to avoid any potential conflict) but have difficulties doing so (see screenshot). Please advise how i can safely uninstall the miniconda that was downloaded via homebrew, while keeping the one via installer intact. Note that path in which the miniconda was installed are 2 different paths for each installation method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall miniconda do the following:

```
brew uninstall --force miniconda
```

Additionally, you might have done `conda init "$(basename "${SHELL}")"` for your respective terminal. To reverse that what I do is write the following: `code .bashrc` or `code .zshrc` in my terminal. This will open the respective file in `VSCODE` and you can delete the chunk of script that activates conda environments in the respective `bash` or `zsh` terminal.

Or you can just use the following:

For Bash

```
conda deactivate
conda config --remove-key "auto_activate_base"
conda init bash --reverse
```

For zsh

```
conda deactivate
conda config --remove-key "auto_activate_base"
conda init zsh --reverse
```

Basically, all it does is delete the `(base)` in your respective terminal by removing the activation script of conda. So, the reverse of the command `conda init "$(basename "${SHELL}")"`.